# Screenshot command is not working in Python

Tags: python, image, automation, screenshot, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui, sys
from PIL import Image

pyautogui.moveTo(1837, 377)
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(2)

img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(940, 292, 190, 90))
img.save(r'C:\Users\chitr\OneDrive\Pictures\screenshot python\hiragana.png')
```

i want to capture a certain region and save it but it only works till `pyautogio.click()` and then the rest doesn't execute.